# Convert String to LocalDateTime with zoned time

Tags: spring-boot, utc, objectmapper

I received a String field in a topic with date and offset and I need to convert this String to a LocalDateTime by adding the offset. For example, if I received:

```
2021-07-20T19:00:00.000+02:00
```

I want to convert in LocalDateTime:

```
2021-07-20T21:00:00.000
```

And I have a Bean with custom object mapper for this purpose:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

     @Bean
    public MyCustomObjectMapper configure() {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX");
        final LocalDateTimeDeserializer dateTimeDeserializer = new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(formatter);
        final LocalDateTimeSerializer dateTimeSerializer = new LocalDateTimeSerializer(formatter);
        
        final JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, dateTimeDeserializer);
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, dateTimeSerializer);
        mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);

        return new MyCustomObjectMapper (mapper);
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work as I expect, since the resulting LocalDateTime offset disappears and is not added:

```
2021-07-20T19:00:00.000
```

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Can you add the class that has the `LocalDateTime` field and include any annotations you have on the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LocalDateTime` class is a date-time representation which is unaware of time zones and it's only logical that the `LocalDateTimeDeserializer` ignores any time zone information in the source data.

To account for the time zone you could use the `InstantDeserializer.OFFSET_DATE_TIME` deserializer (`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is actually the format of the source date time you have) and have its result converted to `LocalDateTime` within a desired zone. This can be wrapped in a custom deserializer for ease of use, e.g.

```
class SmartLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    private final InstantDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> delegate = InstantDeserializer.OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

    public SmartLocalDateTimeDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p,
                                     DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final OffsetDateTime result = delegate.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        return result.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}

...

javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new SmartLocalDateTimeDeserializer());
```